# Change Redirect URL of Joomla Login Page

Tags: authentication, joomla

I am using joomla Login page, but need to change the action page of login, its currently as `form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php', true, $this->params->get('usesecure')); ?>" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" name="com-login" id="com-form-login">`

Need to change to

```
form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_contushdvideoshare&view=myvideos', true, $this->params->get('usesecure')); ?>" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" name="com-login" id="com-form-login">
```

Possible?? Any help to fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you do this via the login module?

Just create a menu item to the url that you want to go to and select it in the "Login Redirection Page" dropdown in the login module parameters.

[image]

Comment: I am not using any login module for that, I know how to do that from Login Module,but I needs some code to be updated in core files as i am working on my core login module. Any help now ?

Comment: @NikitaChopra - As I have always said to people, don't mess with core Joomla files.

Comment: @Lodder Regret to say, but i have made an whole module for header portion, can i call that login module in my core file ?

Comment: not quite sure I understand. why do you need to redirect after login using code?

Comment: Hmm, thought that would still work. You could try overriding the com_user login view and change the login_redirect_url - /components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php in /templates/yourtemplate/html/com_users/login/default_login.php ---- see http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: I need to open bydefault `MYVIDEOS` page after `login` of the users, its redirecting after login to `index.php?option=com_contushdvideoshare&view=myvideos` page but suddenly makes it redirect to `index.php` after using your direction. Any more help ? thanks

Comment: "i am working on my core login module" = I can't understand why you would want to do that but maybe this will help -http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_redirect_users_after_a_successful_login%3F

Answer (score 1):

I myself too had this problem, like I could configure my login modules to redirect to a specific page after successful login, but the com_user login view still redirected to the joomla user profile page. [**This plugin seems to do the trick.**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/login-redirect/15257)

Answer (score 0):

The redirection of the login module is done via the Module Manager.

So, in the Joomla backend, go to the "Module Manager", then open the Login module, and you will see a parameter for it on the right hand side.