# How to get Joomla installed domain

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I need to do custom redirect after login, but i'm not very familiar with the base of Joomla, so i'm did a little hardcode

```
$app->redirect(JRoute::_('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')).'/index.php?option=com_myapp'));
```

But in some cases there are problems, so is it possible somehow determinate what is the default joomla domain/url/path where it is installed so i could use something like `$domain.'/index.php?option=com_myapp'`?

P.S.
Using 2.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the joomla site url using-

```
JURI::base();

JURI::root();
```

`JURI::base()` Result differs according to front and backend

You can check different joomla constant here-

http://docs.joomla.org/Constants

This answer may also be helpful-

[Change Redirect URL of Joomla Login Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820854/change-redirect-url-of-joomla-login-page/12820972#12820972)